# Improve Large ListView Adapter smooth scroll, sometimes jerky

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, listview

I'm trying to see what is making my listview jerk sometimes when scroll, at times it's bad especially when the application first launches.

All the conditions I have are necessary, unless there is something I don't know(highly likely).
I'm not running certain tasks on a seperate thread because they are dependent on the data I receive from the backend(I'm coding both, so backend suggestions are welcome as well). Product is in beta but really need to make this a slightly bit smoother. I'm compressing the images, and they are a bit long but it's not the problem because when I upload the images from the device, I also include the width and height of the image and send that along to the backend. These dimensions come back when loading the list.

One thing I wonder is if calculating/converting the dimensions for the specific device's screen is causing the slight lag. Not sure how resource intensive that task is, but without it(without knowing the dimensions, each row would start out flat and then expand to the actual picture size which would cause the list to jump, so I can't run that calculation on the background either.)

Basically the scrolling isn't bad, but I need to improve this somehow.

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class VListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private boolean isItFromProfile;

    /**
     * fields For number formating, ex. 1000
     * would return 1k in the format method
     */
    private static final NavigableMap<Long, String> suffixes = new TreeMap<>();

    static {
        suffixes.put(1_000L, "k");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000L, "M");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000_000L, "G");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000_000_000L, "T");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000_000_000_000L, "P");
        suffixes.put(1_000_000_000_000_000_000L, "E");
    }

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Post> mDataSource;
    private static double lat;
    private static double lon;

    public VListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> items) {
        mContext = context;
        mDataSource = items;
        //mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        isItFromProfile = false;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public VListAdapter() {

    }

    public VListAdapter(Context baseContext, ArrayList<Post> posts, boolean b) {
        mContext = baseContext;
        mDataSource = posts;
        //mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        isItFromProfile = b;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(baseContext);
    }


    public void addElement(Post post) {
        mDataSource.add(0, post);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDataSource.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDataSource.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        int limit = Math.min(position + 4, getCount());
        for (int i = position; i < limit; i++) {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(((Post) getItem(i)).getFilename().toString()).preload();
        }


//        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads()
//                .detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
//                .penaltyLog().build());



        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, parent, false);

            viewHolder.titleTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.usernameinlist);
            viewHolder.timeago = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.timeago);
            //viewHolder.sharebutton = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
            viewHolder.likesTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likestext);
            viewHolder.viewcount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.viewcount);
            viewHolder.distance = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            viewHolder.footprints = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.footprintcount);
            viewHolder.postText = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.posttext);
            viewHolder.profilePic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.profilethumb);
            viewHolder.caption = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.captiontext);
            viewHolder.moremenu = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.dots);
            viewHolder.likesPic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.likeimage);
            viewHolder.mapitPic = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mapimage);
            viewHolder.playbutton = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
            viewHolder.videoThumb = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.videothumb);
            viewHolder.listphoto = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listphoto);
            viewHolder.rainbow = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rainbow);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }


        final Post post = (Post) getItem(position);
        int color = Color.parseColor("#dddddd");
        viewHolder.likesPic.setColorFilter(color);
        viewHolder.mapitPic.setColorFilter(color);
        viewHolder.moremenu.setColorFilter(color);


        if (Hawk.count() == 0)
            initHawkWithDataFromServer();

        if (isItFromProfile) {
            viewHolder.profilePic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.titleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.distance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(post.getUsername());
        PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime();
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(post.getUploadDate().get$date());
        viewHolder.timeago.setText(prettyTime.format(dateTime.toDate()));
        viewHolder.likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(format(post.getLikes())));
        viewHolder.footprints.setText(String.valueOf(format(post.getLocation().size() - 1)));

        //don't display 0 if there are no likes, just show heart icon
        if (viewHolder.likesTextView.getText().equals("0"))
            viewHolder.likesTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            viewHolder.likesTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



        //don't display 0 if there are no footprints
        if (viewHolder.footprints.getText().equals("0"))
            viewHolder.footprints.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            viewHolder.footprints.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        double[] loc = post.getLocation().get(0);
        viewHolder.distance.setText("~" + PostListFragment.distance(loc[0], loc[1], 'M') + " Miles");
        if (post.getViews() != null)
            viewHolder.viewcount.setText(format(post.getViews()) + (post.getViews() == 1 ? " View" : " Views"));

        String profilePictureS3Url = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/" + post.getUsername()
                + ".jpg";

        String filename = post.getS3link();
        final String videoThumbURL = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/" + filename;


        Glide.with(mContext).load(profilePictureS3Url).asBitmap().centerCrop().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(viewHolder.profilePic) {
            @Override
            protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                        RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(mContext.getResources(), resource);
                circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                viewHolder.profilePic.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
            }
        });

        int height = ((Post) getItem(position)).getHeight();
        int width = ((Post) getItem(position)).getWidth();

        if (height != 0 && width != 0) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewHolder.listphoto.getLayoutParams();
            Resources r = mContext.getResources();
            height = (int) getHeight(height, width);
            params.height = height;
            params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            viewHolder.listphoto.setLayoutParams(params);

        } else {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewHolder.listphoto.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            viewHolder.listphoto.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

        if (post.getType() == null) {
            Glide.clear(viewHolder.listphoto);
            viewHolder.listphoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Glide.clear(viewHolder.listphoto);
            viewHolder.videoThumb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.rainbow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(videoThumbURL).fitCenter()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).dontAnimate().into(viewHolder.videoThumb);
            viewHolder.playbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        if (post.getType() != null) {
            if (post.getType().equals("video")) {
                viewHolder.playbutton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Glide.clear(viewHolder.listphoto);
                viewHolder.listphoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.clear(viewHolder.postText);
                viewHolder.postText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.videoThumb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.rainbow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Glide.with(mContext).load(videoThumbURL).fitCenter()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).dontAnimate().into(viewHolder.videoThumb);

            }

            if (post.getType().equals("image")) {
                Glide.clear(viewHolder.videoThumb);
                viewHolder.videoThumb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.rainbow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.clear(viewHolder.playbutton);
                viewHolder.playbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.clear(viewHolder.postText);
                viewHolder.postText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.listphoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.listphoto.setBottom(0);

                Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getFilename().toString())
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).dontAnimate()
                        .into(viewHolder.listphoto);
            }

            if (post.getType().equals("text")) {
                Glide.clear(viewHolder.videoThumb);
                viewHolder.videoThumb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.rainbow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.clear(viewHolder.playbutton);
                viewHolder.playbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.clear(viewHolder.listphoto);
                viewHolder.listphoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.postText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.postText.setText(post.getText());
            }

        }

        if (Hawk.contains("liked" + post.getId().get$oid())) {
            viewHolder.likesPic.clearColorFilter();
            Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.heartroundorange).into(viewHolder.likesPic);
            ((ImageView) viewHolder.likesPic).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ff3a6f"));
        } else {

            Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.heartroundgray).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(viewHolder.likesPic);
        }


        if (Hawk.contains("mapped" + post.getId().get$oid())) {
            viewHolder.mapitPic.clearColorFilter();
            ((ImageView) viewHolder.mapitPic).setImageResource(R.drawable.dropmaincolororange);
            ((ImageView) viewHolder.mapitPic).setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#444444"));
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.dropdarkgray).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(viewHolder.mapitPic);
        }


        if (!Hawk.contains("mapped" + post.getId().get$oid())) {
            viewHolder.mapitPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Hawk.put("mapped" + post.getId().get$oid(), 1);
                    ((ImageView) viewHolder.mapitPic).setImageResource(R.drawable.dropmaincolororange);
                    viewHolder.footprints.setText(String.valueOf(post.getLocation().size() + 1));
                    post.getLocation().add(new double[]{PostListFragment.lon, PostListFragment.lat});
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            postMappedToServer(post.getId().get$oid());
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();
                    TastyToast.makeText(mContext, "Post dropped off here.", TastyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, TastyToast.CONFUSING);
                }
            });
        } else {
            viewHolder.mapitPic.setClickable(false);
        }

        if (!Hawk.contains("liked" + post.getId().get$oid())) {
            viewHolder.likesPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Hawk.put("liked" + post.getId().get$oid(), 1);
                    viewHolder.likesPic.setClickable(false);
                    ((ImageView) viewHolder.likesPic).setImageResource(R.drawable.heartroundorange);
                    viewHolder.likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(post.getLikes() + 1));
                    post.setLikes(post.getLikes() + 1);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            postLikeToServer(post);
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();
                }
            });
        } else {
            viewHolder.likesPic.setClickable(false);
        }


        if (post.getType() == null || post.getType().equals("video"))
            viewHolder.videoThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (VListAdapter.this.mContext instanceof ProfileFeed) {
                        ((ProfileFeed) VListAdapter.this.mContext).closeActivity();
                    }

                    Intent broadcast = new Intent();
                    broadcast.setAction("com.molehead.openout.POST");

                    broadcast.putExtra("postId", post.getFilename().toString());
                    broadcast.putExtra("hawkId", post.getId().get$oid());
                    broadcast.putExtra("s3link", post.getS3link());
                    broadcast.putExtra("username", post.getUsername());

                    if (Hawk.contains("liked" + post.getId().get$oid()))
                        broadcast.putExtra("liked", "yes");
                    else
                        broadcast.putExtra("liked", "no");

                    broadcast.putExtra("likecount", post.getLikes().toString());

                    App.post = post;
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext.getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(broadcast);
                }
            });

        viewHolder.moremenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext.getApplicationContext(), viewHolder.moremenu, Gravity.CENTER);
                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, popup.getMenu());

                //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_share:
                                String postId = post.getId().get$oid();
                                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                String shareBody = postId + ".jpg"; //https://openout.herokuapp.com/posts/" + postId;
                                String shareSub = "Shared via Molehead";
                                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSub);
                                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                                sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share");
                                new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                mContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity(new_intent);
                                break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show();
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }


    private void initHawkWithDataFromServer() {
        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userinfo", 0);
        String username = settings.getString("username", "ok");
        String password = settings.getString("password", "ok");


        LoginService loginService =
                ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class, username, password);
        final Call<List<Post>> call = loginService.getLikes(username);
        Log.i("lonlat", String.valueOf(lon) + " and  " + String.valueOf(lat));


        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {

                ArrayList<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();
                posts = (ArrayList<Post>) response.body();
                if (!posts.isEmpty())
                    for (Post p : posts) {
                        Hawk.put("liked" + p.getId().get$oid(), 1);
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }


    private void postMappedToServer(String oid) {
        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("userinfo", 0);
        String username = settings.getString("username", "ok");
        String password = settings.getString("password", "ok");
        LoginService loginService =
                ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class, username, password);

        Log.i("postlistfraglat", String.valueOf(PostListFragment.lat));
        Call<ResponseBody> call = loginService.addLocation(oid, PostListFragment.lon, PostListFragment.lat);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                    Log.i("mapped", "success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void postLikeToServer(Post post) {

        SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences("userinfo", 0);
        String username = settings.getString("username", "ok");
        String password = settings.getString("password", "ok");

        LoginService loginService =
                ServiceGenerator.createService(LoginService.class, username, password);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = loginService.like(post, 1, username);


        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("call", response.body().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("MFEED", "like request failed");
            }
        });
    }


    public static String format(long value) {
        //Long.MIN_VALUE == -Long.MIN_VALUE so we need an adjustment here
        if (value == Long.MIN_VALUE) return format(Long.MIN_VALUE + 1);
        if (value < 0) return "-" + format(-value);
        if (value < 1000) return Long.toString(value); //deal with easy case

        Map.Entry<Long, String> e = suffixes.floorEntry(value);
        Long divideBy = e.getKey();
        String suffix = e.getValue();

        long truncated = value / (divideBy / 10); //the number part of the output times 10
        boolean hasDecimal = truncated < 100 && (truncated / 10d) != (truncated / 10);

        return hasDecimal ? (truncated / 10d) + suffix : (truncated / 10) + suffix;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView titleTextView;
        private TextView timeago;
        private TextView likesTextView;
        private TextView viewcount;
        private TextView distance;
        private TextView footprints;
        private ImageView profilePic;
        private ImageView moremenu;
        private ImageView likesPic;
        private ImageView mapitPic;
        private ImageView rainbow;
        //private ImageView sharebutton;
        private TextView caption;
        private ImageView listphoto;
        private ImageView videoThumb;
        private ImageView playbutton;
        private TextView postText;
        private Post post;

    }


    private float getHeight(float height, float width) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return (height * size.x / width);

    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use RecyclerView instead.

Comment: Recycler View is made specialy for this purpose [Recycler View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Comment: According to me, When you write if condition then you should also write else condition. And one more important think is that every condition you have store in other variable(boolean) while you are parsing or getting the data from server.

Comment: @GaneshKatikar  yeah, but wouldn't I be basically starting from scratch almost if converting it to a recyclerview?

Comment: Using recycle-view will helpful to make the code more clean. I think replacing this "if (post.getType().equals("xxxx")) {" by using many kinds of view.

Comment: Please post the layout where you use the `ListView`

Comment: This adapter has some serious problems. You are doing waaay to much stuff inside it. You are dealing with clicks and server calls. This violates the single responsibility principle. You should only use your data to print the data in the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Change your implementation to `RecyclerView` which is more efficient in terms of scrapping views or recycling.
- We can also enable optimizations if the items are static and will not change for significantly smoother scrolling:

  ```
  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
  ```
- Create an intent service and register `BroadcastReceiver` as data return callback or error callback when api request, business rule, data modification completed. Use synchronous call to execute `initHawkWithDataFromServer()` in advance and after getting result from api continue modifying or applying business logic. After that create new adapter or update existing adapter data set.
- Move all the below data calculation or data value formatting  logic from adapter's `getView()` to above intent service.

  You can add more getter and setter to existing Post pojo.

  ```
  DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(post.getUploadDate().get$date()); 
  viewHolder.timeago.setText(prettyTime.format(dateTime.toDate()));
  viewHolder.likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(format(post.getLikes())));
  viewHolder.footprints.setText(String.valueOf(format(post.getLocation().size)) - 1)));

  Post{
      //Your existing property
      @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
      //equals neither serialize nor deserialize or
      private DateTime uploadedDateTime;
      //etc. prettyTime.format, String.valueOf
  }
  ```
- Removes unnecessary reflection:

  ```
  GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
  builder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
  Gson gson = builder.create();
  new  Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
  ```

  and it to your retrofit Service creation class.
  You can also use transient(`private transient DateTime uploadedDateTime;`)
- Remove 
  `public void addElement(Post post) { mDataSource.add(0, post);
  this.notifyDataSetChanged();}`
  and whenever you need to notify if a single or more items inserted, deleted etc. Use the below:

  ```
  notifyItemChanged(int)
  notifyItemInserted(int)
  notifyItemRemoved(int)
  notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)
  notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)
  notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)
  ```

We can use these from the activity or fragment:

```
//Add a new contact
items.add(0, new Post("Barney"));
//Notify the adapter that an item was inserted at position 0
adapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

Above methods are more efficient. Every time we want to add or remove items from the `RecyclerView`, we will need to explicitly inform to the adapter of the event. Unlike the `ListView` adapter, a `RecyclerView` adapter should not rely on `notifyDataSetChanged()` since the more granular actions should be used. [See the API documentation for more details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

Also, if you are intending to update an existing list, make sure to get the current count of items before making any changes. For instance, a `getItemCount()` on the adapter should be called to record the first index that will be changed.

```
// record this value before making any changes to the existing list
int curSize = adapter.getItemCount(); // replace this line with wherever you get new records
ArrayList<Post> newItems = Post.createPostsList(20);
// update the existing list
items.addAll(newItems);
// curSize should represent the first element that got added
// newItems.size() represents the itemCount
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(curSize, newItems.size());
```

**Diffing Larger Changes**

A new `DiffUtil` class has been added in the v24.2.0 of the support library to help compute the difference between the old and new list. [Details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility)

- Don't preload images via glide if your image sizes are different. [Try creating your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38219830/2870088). [Also try looking at](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads).
- Create color as the class member

  ```
  int color = Color.parseColor("#dddddd");
  ```
- Write `View.GONE` or `View.VISIBLE` in Post pojo itself, which will be executed in background thread from Retrofit if IntentService. Try api return boolean in json instead "0" as String.
- Move all below to IntentService
  //don't display 0 if there are no likes, just show heart icon
      if (viewHolder.likesTextView.getText().equals("0"))
          viewHolder.likesTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      else
          viewHolder.likesTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  ```
  //don't display 0 if there are no footprints
  if (viewHolder.footprints.getText().equals("0"))
      viewHolder.footprints.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  else
      viewHolder.footprints.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  double[] loc = post.getLocation().get(0);
  viewHolder.distance.setText("~" + PostListFragment.distance(loc[0], loc[1], 'M') + " Miles");
  ```
- All String concatenation also in Post or IntnetService like:

  ```
  String profilePictureS3Url = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/moleheadphotos/" + post.getUsername() + ".jpg";
  ```

Also you can create color filter in advance and one time only. Remove scrollbar from listview as it calculates height to show scroll bar.

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible to point to a specific issue because there is so much code in your Adapter. One thing is sure, though - switching to `RecyclerView` won't help you in this case.

Adapters should not contain business logic - they should only "adapt" input objects to the underlying Views. In your case, it seems like the adapter performs calculations, spawns new threads, performs network requests, etc.

You need to refactor your code such that the adapter will be similar to this:

```
public class PostsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {


    private Context mContext;

    public PostsListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void bindPosts(List<Post> posts) {
        clear();
        addAll(posts);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            // assign new View to convertView
            // create new ViewHolder
            // set ViewHolder as tag of convertView
            // set listeners
        } else {
            // get a reference to existing ViewHolder
        }

        // populate ViewHolder's elements with data from getItem(position)
        // kick off asynchronous loading of images
        // NOTE: no calculations allowed here - just simple bidding of data to Views

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Your code needs to be structured in such a way, that business logic that involves calculations and transformation of data executed before you bind a new data to `ListView`, and `Post` objects that you pass to `bindPosts()` method already contain the results of the aforementioned calculations and transformations.

Adapter just "adapts" the final data from `Posts` to `Views` - nothing more.

If you're short on time now, and just need to "make it work", then I would start by removing the logic that spawns new threads and makes network requests. See if this improves performance.

Comment: Have you read the https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html sequence of training docs?  Using the cache made a huge difference in scrolling smoothness for my image GridView.

Comment: He has a lot of commands to adjust the view like setVisible, setLayout base on the data. So using recycle-view will help him make the code better and the performance will improve a little bit.

Comment: @VõQuangHòa, The two most "performace hungry" parts that I see in OP's code are threads and networking related logic. Usage of `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` with `ViewHolder` pattern is not guaranteed to be faster (surprise, surprise), and even if it will happen to be faster in this case, the performance improvement due to this change will be negligible compared to performance inefficiency of threading and networking logic, and, therefore, unnoticeable. OP should definitely start with refactoring of networking and threading out of the adapter.

Comment: @Vasiliy I agree, the main reason "performance hungry" is too much threads and networking related logic.

Comment: Thanks everyone, yeah you are correct, I'm moving some logic away from the adapter

Comment: removing Hawk.count ... and initHawkWith... did not improve performance

Comment: @franklinexpress, don't forget to remove Glide "preloading" logic - it gets executed too many times and is too related to threading and networking.

Answer (score 1):

Too many things to improve here. Here is some examples.

I see this

```
if (Hawk.count() == 0)
        initHawkWithDataFromServer();
```

I believe that the method initHawkWithDataFromServer will be called many times during the time the list appears.

This call can be done only once when the activity was created.

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(videoThumbURL).fitCenter()
```

But you should refactor your code first, moving the logic to another class. Try to remove some code like this (it should be done by using some layout attribites)

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = viewHolder.listphoto.getLayoutParams();
        Resources r = mContext.getResources();
        height = (int) getHeight(height, width);
        params.height = height;
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        viewHolder.listphoto.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Hawk.count() should only get called once, after the first call, the data is save on the device, so on a second call count will != 0

Comment: @franklinexpress it's not correct. I can see the function call the web api asynchronously, so the condition there is not enough. It will be called once or many time depend on the internet connection (slow or fast). I recommend you put some Log.i(...) inside that function to see how it works.