# How to load image using glide in advance?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

Actually I'm trying to load images into my `reycycleview` using `glide 4.4.0` and it's loading fine . But now the problem is my `recyclerview` is lagging a bit when I scroll fast due to the image loading . But I saw some of the glide's method called `preload` and `downloadOnly` .So,my question is  **are these methods helpful for loading image in advance if so then how to use them?**

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38219830/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar thanks for your time sir I'll try to use it

Comment: I had this kind of issue, not in a list but the preload one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37964187/preload-multiple-images-with-glide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/recyclerview.html) to fine-tune your preloading. It requires quite a bit of work but looks promising.

In short, you need to create a PreLoader class that will get image URLs from your data set:

```
private class MyPreloadModelProvider implements PreloadModelProvider {
    @Override
    @NonNull
    public List<U> getPreloadItems(int position) {
      String url = myUrls.get(position);
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
      }
      return Collections.singletonList(url);
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public RequestBuilder getPreloadRequestBuilder(String url) {
        return 
            GlideApp.with(fragment)
              .load(url) 
              .override(imageWidthPixels, imageHeightPixels);
    }
}
```

And then you set it as a scroll listener on your recycler view:

```
PreloadSizeProvider sizeProvider = 
    new FixedPreloadSizeProvider(imageWidthPixels, imageHeightPixels);
PreloadModelProvider modelProvider = new MyPreloadModelProvider();
RecyclerViewPreloader<Photo> preloader = 
    new RecyclerViewPreloader<>(
        Glide.with(this), modelProvider, sizeProvider, 10 /*maxPreload*/);

RecyclerView myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) result.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(preloader);
```

After this, you'll get your images preloaded before the onBondViewHolder callback in the adapter, and you'll be able to display them from the cache.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
  ImageView imageView = ((MyViewHolder) viewHolder).imageView;
  String currentUrl = myUrls.get(position);

  GlideApp.with(fragment)
    .load(currentUrl)
    .override(imageWidthPixels, imageHeightPixels)
    .into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion sir , I'll inform you about it's performance after implementing it

Comment: Do you know if there is some way of using the recycler integration with other than LinearLayoutManager?